# Loop through the list of tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, loops

Is there any way to rewrite the following SQL script

```
insert ignore into autotest.Econstant
select * from staging.Econstant;

insert ignore into autotest.Elanguage
select * from staging.Elanguage;

insert ignore into autotest.groups
select * from staging.groups;
```

to something like

```
for %table_name% in [Econstant, Elanguage, groups] do
begin
  insert ignore into autotest.%table_name%
  select * from staging.%table_name%;
end
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html